# TCL:: How to print numbers from 10 to 1 using while loop in TCL (How to decrement the variiable value)

Tags: while-loop, tcl

TCL Script:

```
set a 10
while {$a < 1} {
    puts $a
    incr a
}
```

Expected output:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

I am trying to print numbers from 10 to 1. But its not working (It prints nothing).

Is there a way to "decrement" the variable value (decr a)?

Thanks,

Kumar

Comment: `while $a is less than 1` but $a is 10 so it doesn't even enter the while loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the condition to `$a > 1` and to decrement the value, you have to use `incr a -1`. Here we gave the step as -1.

Answer (score 1):

same can be done by for loop also

```
for {set i 10} {$i > 1} {incr i -1} {
puts $i

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your loop body is never executed because the condition yields false the very first time. You probably wanted to write ">" instead of "<".

Answer (score 0):

```
set a 10
while {$a > 0} {
    puts  $a
    incr a -1
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**